# How to create a touch event in a fragment for add/delete nodes(with grathstream)?

Tags: java, android, graphstream

I'm creating an application that creates graphs (nodes and edges), I wanted to implement a touch method to create the node, but I'm having difficulty, because when I touch the canvas to add the node it does not work, but if I click the bottom menu of activity works

I tried implements View.OnTouchListener however this does not recognize the touch in the FrameLayout that is with the fragment where I display the graph.

my activity:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/layoutFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavView"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

<fragment
  android:id="@+id/fragment_tag"    
  android:name="org.graphstream.ui.android_viewer.util.DefaultFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

<include
   android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
   layout="@layout/bottom_nav_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my java(I was trying to touch the screen and show a toast):

```
    public class FragmentGrafo extends Fragment{

    @Override
     public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
    container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grafo_fragment, 
    container, false);

        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Não pode mais add 
     nós", 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

I hope I can touch the screen and add the node, or click and remove the no, select node 1 and then node 2 and create an edge

Comment: Don't you want to create a custom view to handle drawing like this? then add an onTouchListener when you initialise the view

Comment: I am using the graphstream api, I found the net speaking that to use the touch I have to create a ViewerPipe so it is returning null exception